# How I can make objects emit light?

Tags: lighting

Is there a way I can make objects emit light, as if they were lamps?

Comment: No one "*took away*" anything, and certainly not us BSE denizens. Could you clarify what you mean, what render engine you are using, and what you wish to achieve?

Comment: @cegaton You say that, but it's not that simple to do in BE.

Comment: @someonewithpc now that the question has been reopened feel free to write an answer : ) I hardly ever use BI...